# What class this graph connectivity problem belong to

Tags: graphs

We are given a Boolean circuit $C(x_1, \dots, x_n,y_1, \dots, y_n)$ with $2n$ inputs and we have to determine if the graph $G_C = (V_C, E_C)$ (specified below) is connected:
$$V_C = \{0,1\}^n, \\ E_C = \{((a_1, \dots, a_n), (b_1, \dots, b_n)) : C(a_1, \dots, a_n,b_1, \dots,b_n) = 1\}.$$

To which class this problem belongs? I know that graph connectivity can be done so fast (as fast as to be in **P**) and using a small amount of space. Does this is different in this particular graph? Is this problem in **P**, **EXP**, **PSPACE**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G$ has $2^n$ vertices, and for any two vertices $v_i,v_j$ we can check whether $(v_i,v_j)\in E$ in polynomial time (since circuit value problem is in P). By executing DFS on $G$ from any vertex you can find out whether $G$ is strongly connected in $O(|V|+|E|)=O\left(2^{2n}\right)$ time, which puts your problem in $E$, as the circuit's description is of size $\Omega(n)$.

Your problem is PSPACE-hard. Given a machine $M$ which uses $\le n^c$ space and input $x$, denote by $G_x$ its computation graph, i.e. the graph whose vertices are all possible configurations using $\le |x|^c$ cells and $(C_i,C_j)\in E_{G_x}$ iff $C_i$ is followed by $C_j$ in the computation of $M$. Now adjust $G_x$ by adding edges from every vertex to $C_x$, the initial configuration of $M$ on input $x$, and from the accepting configuration $C_{acc}$ (assume without loss of generality that it's unique) to all other vertices. Clearly this new graph $G_x'$ is strongly connected iff there is a path from the from $C_x$ to $C_{acc}$ in $G_x$. Given $M,x$ you can construct in polynomial time a circuit $C_{G_x'}$ that takes two vertices $C_i,C_j$ of $G_x'$ and outputs 1 iff there is an edge from $C_i$ to $C_j$ (checking whether one configuration is immediately followed by another is easy). I leave it to you to complete the details here.